# How do i store position and direction vectors

Tags: c++

**drone.cc**

```
#include "drone.h"

namespace dr {

Drone::Drone(std::vector<float> position, std::vector<float> direction, 
                                        const picojson::object& details) {
  //store the position and direction vectors.
}

const std::vector<float>& Drone::GetPosition() const {
  return this->position;
}

const std::vector<float>& Drone::GetDirection() const {
  return this->direction;
}
}
```

drone.h

```
#include "entity_base.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace dr {

class Drone : public dr::EntityBase {
 public:
  Drone(std::vector<float> pos, std::vector<float> direction, const picojson::object& obj);

  const std::vector<float>& GetPosition() const;

  const std::vector<float>& GetDirection() const;

 private:
   vector<float> position;
   vector<float> direction;
};

}
```

when I try to compile I get an error saying invalid initialization of ref of type 'const std::vector&' from the expression of type 'const float'. How can this be fixed, I'm stuck on this and can't think of anything.

Comment: Please include the exact error message in the question and indicate where it occurs.

Comment: Nothing wrong here, please show a [mre] that actually reproduces the error. And take a closer look at the messge you get, it will tell you exactly where the error occurred.

Comment: I get an error saying invalid initialization of ref of type 'const std::vector&' from the expression of type 'const float'. I know that we need to store the position and direction vector in the .cc but I don't know how to do that as I cant think of anything for it.

Comment: If you put a [mre] in the question so that we can try to compile it and get the same error it'll be easier to help. The code you've shown does not produce that error since we don't have access to classes you've used in the question. Remove those and [it compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/aWsbM7).

Comment: In physics, a vector usually has two components: magnitude and direction.  A position (in 3d space, using Cartesian coordinates), has 3 components, usually `x, y, z` or height, length and width.  You may want to combine them into one struct or class.  It's kind of difficult to position a drone without any of the 5 attributes.

Comment: When deciding to use parallel arrays, always consider using a single array of a class or struct that contains each element.  In your case, you would have one array of a struct that contains both position and direction.

Comment: Well, we can only guess. Maybe the error is where you initialuze an instance of `Drone`. It might be the case that you pass a `float` where a `std::vector<float>` is expected.  If you don't provide more code we sadly can't answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
  Drone::Drone(
        std::vector<float> p,
        std::vector<float> d,
        const picojson::object& details)
        : position( p )
        , direction( d )
    {
    
    }
```

Comment: OK.  Post the complete code and the actual error message.